# PHP GD gives error

Tags: php, gd

Update: TTF file seems to be there after testing.
Update: changed to a relative path for the font file.  Still doesn't work.

I get the following error when I try to make an image using GD through PHP.

> [Tue Sep 01 19:44:15 2009] [error]
>   [client *IP ADDRESS*] PHP Warning: 
>   imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]:
>   Could not find/open font in
>   /www/vhosts/website.com/htdocs/trial/TextToImage.class.php
>   on line 38

I changed the path for the font as it was giving me the same error.  I added the font to the server by dropping the file into the folder.  What am I missing?

```
/**
 * @name                    : makeImageF
 *
 * Function for create image from text with selected font.
 *
 * @param String $text     : String to convert into the Image.
 * @param String $font     : Font name of the text.
 * @param int    $W        : Width of the Image.
 * @param int    $H        : Hight of the Image.
 * @param int     $X        : x-coordinate of the text into the image.
 * @param int    $Y        : y-coordinate of the text into the image.
 * @param int    $fsize    : Font size of text.
 * @param array  $color       : RGB color array for text color.
 * @param array  $bgcolor  : RGB color array for background.
 *
 */
public function makeImageF($text, $font="/www/vhosts/website.com/htdocs/trial/CENTURY.TTF", $W=200, $H=20, $X=0, $Y=0, $fsize=18, $color=array(0x0,0x0,0x0), $bgcolor=array(0xFF,0xFF,0xFF)){

    $this->im = @imagecreate($W, $H)
        or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($this->im, $bgcolor[0], $bgcolor[1], $bgcolor[2]);        //RGB color background.
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($this->im, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);            //RGB color text.

    imagettftext($this->im, $fsize, $X, $Y, $fsize, $text_color, $font, $text);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the font with the class/index file and using it via a relative path, just to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a font file in a format unknown to your version of libgd.
The gd section of the output of [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) should include version of the FreeType/T1Lib library. Which one is it?
And what does

```
echo '<pre>Debug: '; passthru('file '.$font); echo "</pre>\n";
// imagettftext($this->im, $fsize, $X, $Y, $fsize, $text_color, $font, $text);
```

print?

Edit: oops, forget about the the type of the font file. The error for that would be `Could not read font`. `Could not find/open font` really means what it says: either there is no such file or it cannot be accessed.
The output of `passthru('file '.$font);` is "only" `CENTURY.TTF: TrueType font data`? Then you've used a relative path. Try passing an absolute path to imagettftext()

```
$font_realpath = realpath($font);
if ( !$font_realpath || !is_file($font_realpath) ) {
  die 'no such font file';
}
else if ( !is_readable($font_realpath) ) {
  die 'cannot read font file';
}
imagettftext($this->im, $fsize, $X, $Y, $fsize, $text_color, $font_realpath, $text);
```

Comment: Below is everything from the GD portion of the phpinfo file.  So Freetype is 2.2.1.  There is no t1lib on the phpinfo page at all.

GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.28 compatible)
FreeType Support  enabled
FreeType Linkage  with freetype
FreeType Version  2.2.1
GIF Read Support  enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support  enabled
PNG Support  enabled
WBMP Support  enabled
XBM Support  enabled

Comment: Ok, now let's check the type of the font file.

Comment: Debug: CENTURY.TTF: TrueType font data  I had to comment out the rest of the img.php file to get it to work.  If that matters.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the way you are calling the function - add this to the function to help you further

```
if (!file_exists($font))
    die("Font not found ($font)");
if (!is_readable($font))
    die("Font exists but not readable ($font)");
```

Also check the font path is absolute and doesn't start with a slash, the manual page for [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) states

> Depending on which version of the GD
> library PHP is using, when fontfile
> does not begin with a leading / then
> .ttf will be appended  to the filename
> and the library will attempt to search
> for that filename along a
> library-defined font path.

Answer (score 0):

Does the web server (the user that runs the web server) have read access to that folder/file?

Comment: Is there a good way of testing for this?  I can browse to the font file online and download it from my server.  I would assume that would make your answer yes.

Comment: The answer by Paul Dixon, file_exists + is_readable, should test for existence of the file and its readability.